# Flutter build error : Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle

I try to build apk in my flutter application. I am got one warning and one error. Warning message : Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2.

Error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Abdulkadhar\Documents\Android\AppDevelopment\Production\simply2be_production\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.

         > Transform's input file does not exist: C:\Users\Abdulkadhar\Documents\Android\AppDevelopment\Production\simply2be_production\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 4m 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          243.1s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My app gradle

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
       
        applicationId "app.projects.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }}
```

My build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'//4.0.0'//3.3.2 //3.5.3 //3.4.2
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 29
                buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }}
```

Here are my Gradle wrapper properties in case they are also important.

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

My gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```